# Как из текущей страницы xaml сделать PDF, со всеми данными и графикой

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, pdf, wpf-canvas

OpenFileDialog не подходит Очень много посмотрел, ничего не подходит[image: Это необходимо превратить в PDF при условии что "Иванов Иван" и т.д. могут меняться]

Comment: Не используйте контролы как место хранения данных! Забудьте про `MyTextBox.Text = "Привет мир!"`, научитесь делать привязки. Сделайте класс с нужными свойствами, его привяжите, все, у вас есть один класс с нужными данными, который вы можете десериализовать или что либо еще дальше с ним делать.

Comment: Найдите PDF библиотеку, создайте руками красивый PDF шаблон, загрузите шаблон библиотекой и запишите в него текст в нужных местах. WPF здесь вообще не при чем, XAML - для интерфейса, а не для печати документов. Конечно, можно еще скриншот онка сделать и засунуть картинку в PDF - но это неприкольно, чтоли, и качество документа будет ниже, и весить он будет больше.